# Importing sql files to DB via Terminal. Is there a way to set default value for "ERROR 1366 at line ***: Incorrect integer value: ''?

Tags: mysql, bash, terminal

Using terminal (ubuntu 15.10_64 + mysql 5.6) Im inserting sql files to database by this command:

```
for i in *.sql;
do mysql -u login_name -pPassword countries_mysql < $i;
done
```

where *.sql files contain strings like:

```
insert into region (id,vkl,tip,samonazvanie,mfa,stolica,samonazvanie_1,oficialno_1,cvet,flag,flag_svg,gerb,gerb_svg,mir_id,obj_id,kontinent,strana_id,region_id,ksi1,ksi2,ksi_sort,ksi_lat,iso_kod,gn_kod,telefon,pochta,avto,naselenie,ploshad,giddom,shirota_gradus,shirota_minuta,shirota_sekunda,dolgota_gradus,dolgota_minuta,dolgota_sekunda,sozdan,izmenen,vrem_pojas,dop_nazvanie,status,reforma_id,sxema_maska,tabl_id,tabl,pre_tabl,pre_id,post_tabl,post_id,uroven,nazvanie_1,opisanie_1,nazvanie_2,opisanie_2) VALUES ('60448','0','0','gmina Zalesie','','0','','','','','','','','0','0','0','130','52529','','','','','','','','','','0.000','0.000','http://www.giddom.com','0','0','0.00','0','0','0.00','2013-05-02 01:47:11','2015-01-25 13:21:36','','','8','0','0','0','','','0','','0','3','Залесе','');
```

and I receive a lot (thousands) of errors of this kind:

```
ERROR 1366 (HY000) at line 61891: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'post_id' at row 1
```

Is there any way using bash or anything else, without changing sql files, to set default value for column 'post_id' in case of error?
Something like:

```
if post_id == '':
    post_id = '0'
```

or somehow intercept errors.

I tried to find the answer in internet and at SO, but found php solutions (I do not work with php) or by editing sql files (I have 200 files and some of them have about 1M lines).

I cant make new correct dumps, because files downloaded from internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quickest way is to probably change the definition for the column to varchar, do the imports, substitute NULLs in the case of empty strings and then change the post_id column back to the original data type.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the definition of the table, alter the column to define a default value, with something like

```
...    
col_name INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
...
```